# How to guarantee that my app will always receive every incoming SMS without fail?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have an app which needs to read every incoming SMS messages. I wrote that by writing a `BroadcastReceiver` and registered to listen for the intent - `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`. Later I realised that it can only receive the broadcasts while the process is in foreground.

As per suggestion in `BroadcastReceiver`'s Javadoc I looked at [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). This looked promising but even this could get killed in case of low memory. I have also seen apps which allow the users to kill background processes, so they too could kill it.

So, how does the bundled SMS client manages to always receive and store the SMS messages?

Comment: This might help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: @SunilMishra Not sure how this will help me.

Comment: If you set intent-filter for a `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`in your BR, your broadcast receiver will be registered after the boot event is completed.

Comment: @SunilMishra Are you suggesting that after registering my receiver my app will always receive the broadcasts even when my app is not running later? As the answer below too suggests that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your receiver in Android Manifest file. After user launches your app at least once, it will become active. Your receiver will always be notified then. Even if your app is not running and there is an SMS, Android will start your app and send broadcast to it.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) you can read more about BroadcastReceiver lifecycle.

Comment: I have been through that, but I can't see any text which validates - "Even if your app is not running and there is an SMS, Android will start your app and send broadcast to it."

Comment: It is not explicitly said anywhere. But you can prove it by stopping your app and simulating an SMS using Emulator Control in Eclipse. You will see, that your app will be launched. The only exception from this is, when you _force stop_ your app via stock Apps settings. In this case your app gets deactivated and BroadcastReceivers will be deactivated too. To activate it again, you just need to launch the app anew.

Comment: Okay, so in this case is it necessary to mention the intent in manifest or doing so programmatically too is fine?

Comment: Static registration inside Manifest.xml is crucial in this case.

Comment: I found a reference in official doc which explicitly says that if needed receivers would be instantiated to receive the broadcasts. Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: this will not work if user force stop app from app setting.